# Why is 12.04 running so slow?

Tags: 12.04

I installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 12.04, and when I boot it is slow, everything is slow mouse movement loading an application etc. When I boot using "Recovery Mode" is is very snappy. What is causing the slowness?

Comment: You'll need to give more information. Try opening a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t), writing 'top' without the quote marks and hit Enter. That will display all running processes and should show whether any are hogging the processor or memory. If so, post the output here for more help.

Comment: Slow is relative.

Comment: There is no process that is taking up much memory, the maximum one is 0.9% "compiz", and CPU is all at 0.

Comment: My 12.04 is the fastest Ubuntu ever...I am afraid we need more information in order to be able to help you. Any other symptoms?

Comment: I see that the background loads, the left navigation bar loads, top black bar loads but no icons show up in it (battery, sound, networks, etc). I installed using ext4 if that matters...

Comment: hard to tell, but sounds to me like a faulty installation. Did you check the MDSUM of your .iso file before creating a liveCD or live USB? Is the system the same when you boot from a live image?

Comment: I didn't, how can I do that?

Comment: I had a similar problem, It turned out to be my graphic card driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was on Ubuntu 64-bit, so I switched to Ubuntu 32-bit and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that either your computer can't handle Ubuntu 12.08 well or you need to install/enable the latest drivers for your computer.

I would suggest that you disable unity and use lxde or something other GUI that uses less resources.

Comment: 12.08? I heard he uses 12.04, and heard of 12.10, but 12.08?